# Problemas parar unir tabelas com UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, query, union

Estou tentando trazer os 3 primeiros colocados da minha tabela e também os 2 últimos colocados, [SITE PARA EXECUTAR SCRIPT](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Esse é meu progresso atual que não funciona

```
SELECT ('Podium: ' ||TEAM) as name  
FROM LEAGUE
ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 3;
  UNION ALL
SELECT ('Demoted: ' ||TEAM) as name 
FROM LEAGUE
ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Fiz uma base que pode ser usada no fiddle para quem quiser me ajudar.

```
    CREATE TABLE league
        (
            position INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
            team VARCHAR(45)
        );
```

```
   INSERT INTO league VALUES(1, 'The Quack Bats');
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(2, 'The Responsible Hornets');    
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(3, 'The Bawdy Dolphins'); 
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(4, 'The Abstracted Sharks');  
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(5, 'The Nervous Zebras'); 
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(6, 'The Oafish Owls');    
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(7, 'The Unequaled Bison');    
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(8, 'The Keen Kangaroos'); 
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(9, 'The Left Nightingales');  
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(10, 'The Terrific Elks'); 
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(11, 'The Lumpy Frogs');   
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(12, 'The Swift Buffalo'); 
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(13, 'The Big Chargers');  
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(14, 'The Rough Robins');  
    INSERT INTO league VALUES(15, 'The Silver Crocs');
```

Comment: não é só tirar o ponto-e-vírgula que sobrou ali depois do `LIMIT 3`?

Answer (score 2):

Tenta assim:

```
  SELECT position,
         'Podium' AS tipo,
         team
    FROM (SELECT *
            FROM league
           ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 3) v
   UNION
  SELECT position,
         'Demoted' AS tipo,
         team
    FROM (SELECT *
            FROM league
           ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT 2) v

ORDER BY 1;
```